# Sick Day Entitlement based on years of service with a company

Tags: php, cakephp

got an update for you with my function. This also now works as it should, but I need it to work out total sick, based on years of service up to the 1st day they take of sick. Hope I have made that clear. I have marked the line of code that works out my sick but i only gives me one all the time, even when I know where are more years for that selected user.

Please help?

Glenn Curtis

```
function sickDay($id = null) {
    if($this->CURRENT_USER['User']['role_id'] > 3) { //directors and admins
        /*if(empty($this->data) || !isset($this->data['Holiday']['id'])) {

        } else {*/
        //Get the user sick days
        $userSickDays = $this->Holiday->find(
            'all',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Holiday.holidaystype_id' => 3,
                    'Holiday.user_id' => $id
                ),
                'order' => 'Holiday.startson ASC'
            ));

        //Get years of service
        $userContracts = $this->Holiday->User->Contract->find(
            'all',
                array(
                    'conditions' => array( 'Contract.user_id' => $id), //$data['user_id']),
                    'order' => array( 'Contract.startson' => 'ASC' )
            ));

        //Loop through the user's sick days
        foreach ($userSickDays as $k => $sickDay) {
            //Get number of days in the current sick day
            $totSickdays = $this->Holiday->getNumberDaysFromHoliday($sickDay['Holiday']['id']);

            //Get number of sick days for the past 12 months
            if($k > 0) {
                for($i=0; $i<$k; $i++) {
                    if((strtotime(gmdate("Y-m-d", $sickDay['Holiday']['startson'])." -1 year GMT")) <= $userSickDays[$i]['Holiday']['startson']) {
                        $totSickdays += $this->Holiday->getNumberDaysFromHoliday($userSickDays[$i]['Holiday']['id']);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach ($userContracts as $y => $contract) {

        THIS LINE HERE->$yearsService = $contract['Contract']['startson'] <= $sickDay['Holiday']['startson'];

                if ($contract['Contract']['startson'] <= $sickDay['Holiday']['startson']) {

                    if ($yearsService <= 1) {
                        $entitlement = 10;
                        $remaingDays = $entitlement - $totSickdays;
                        //echo 'one year';
                    } elseif ($yearsService <= 2) {
                        $entitlement = 20;
                        $remaingDays = $entitlement - $totSickdays;
                        //echo 'two years';
                    } elseif ($yearsService <= 4) {
                        $entitlement = 40;
                        $remaingDays = $entitlement - $totSickdays;
                        //echo 'up to five years';
                    } elseif ($yearsService >= 5) {
                        $entitlement = 60;
                        $remaingDays = $entitlement - $totSickdays;
                        //echo 'five years or more';
                    } else {
                        $entitlement = 0;
                        $remaingDays = 0;
                        //echo 'no sick pay';
                    }

                } //End of if statement.
            } //End of $userContracts Foreach Loop


            debug($yearsService);                           
        } //End of Foreach Loop

        //$this->render('/artists/holidayslist');
        //} //End For if empty check
    } // End for if CURRENT_USER
    die();
} //End of Function
```

---

### OLD POST BELOW

Now I have asked for help on this before, however that was over one selected area of my function, to get number of sick days. That now works, I found a function that was built for me within the site I am working on. So I have total number of sick days entered within the database. Now I don't seem to be able to work out why I cant set that to my years of service.

To make my myself more clearly, the outcome of this function is to check the current users sick taken within a selected year. But to a annual year, a contracted year, e.g. may to may.

That is why I have a number of if statements to set up the users entitlement, as that changed based on years of service. Then when that is set, to take off the sick days the user has taken within that contracted year.

I hope I have explain what I want to do, if that is not clear, please let me know and I try and explain in more detail.

Please help, this is written for a page used in a CakePHP project.

Many Many Thanks

Glenn Curtis

```
function sickDay($id = null) {
    if($this->CURRENT_USER['User']['role_id'] > 3) { //directors and admins
        //Caculate if it's a full pay, half pay or nothing
        //$data = $this->data['Holiday'];

        //Get Holidaytypes
        $userSickDays = $this->Holiday->find(
            'all',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Holiday.holidaystype_id' => 3,
                    'Holiday.user_id' => $id
                )
            )
        );

        //Get starting date
        $contracts = $this->Holiday->User->Contract->find(
            'all',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Contract.user_id' => $id //$data['user_id']
                ),
                'order' => array(
                    'Contract.startson' => 'ASC'
                )
            )
        );

        $start = array_shift($contracts);
        $end = array_pop($contracts);
        $endDate = $end['Contract']['endson'];
        $startDate = $start['Contract']['startson'];

        if (empty($endDate)) { $endDate = time('now'); }

        $SortEnd = strftime("%Y", $endDate);
        $SortStart = strftime("%Y", $startDate);
        $YearsService = $SortEnd - $SortStart;

        //Get How Many sick days
        foreach ($userSickDays as $sickDay) {
            $typesDataEnds =  strtotime($sickDay['Holiday']['endson']);
            $typesDataStarts = $sickDay['Holiday']['startson'];

            $DateNow = date('U', strtotime('Now'));

            $GetSickDays = $this->Holiday->getNumberDaysFromHoliday($sickDay['Holiday']['id']);

            $TotalSick += $GetSickDays;

            if ($YearsService <= 1) {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 5;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 5;
                    //echo 'one year';
            } elseif ($YearsService <= 2) {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 10;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 10;
                    //echo 'two years';
            } elseif ($YearsService <= 5) {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 20;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 20;
                    //echo 'up to five years';
            } elseif ($YearsService >= 6) {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 30;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 30;
                    //echo 'five years or more';
            } else {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 0;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 0;
                    //echo 'no sick pay';
            }

        } 
        //$this->render('/artists/holidayslist');

    } // End for if CURRENT_USER
    die();
} //End of Function
```

Comment: what doesn't actually work? You aren't returning or outputting anything. What should the output be and what are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I cleaned up the code a little to remove all my debugs, the outcome should just be true or false. So if the user is in the second year of contract, they get 10 at full paid days and 10 at half pay. For example if that user then has 22 days of in that year, 2 days would not be payable, so false. For another example, if the same year had only taken 3 days, then outcome should be true.

This outcome would then be passed on to a view.cpt file where the sick days are listed, then if true display normal, if false, then display the entry in red.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems too complicated for what (it seems) is just

`return (($TotalAnnualEntitlement - $SickDaysTakenThisYear) > 0) ? true : false;`

You need to work out their entitlement, based on how long they have been contracted - easy enough, You then need to take their entitled holiday from the number of days they have already taken. Again, seems easy enough.

If they have any days remaining, you want to return true. If there have used their allowance, or gone over, return false.

or am i missing something?

Comment: That is what I want to do, yes but totalentitlement is not set anywhere within my db, I have to check for that based on years of service, which again is not stored anywhere within the database. What I want to do, I agree, seem very simple but I am new to cake, although I think its a PHP issue here not cake. But I just can't seem to get it to do what I want.